# Matplotlib ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.7

I am trying to `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in my IDLE on my Macbook.  When running my code I receive the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/owner/Desktop/algo/datareader1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I have installed `matplotlib` with my terminal using `pip3` and to make sure I tried to re-install but received ''Already Satisfied''

Any Ideas as to what the issue could be?

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2002,1,1)

end = dt.datetime(2020,1,10)

df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Do you use Python 3.7 in DLE? What is the first line of the output when you start IDLE? As a side note, the error is on line 2. There is no point to include the rest of your code in the question.

Comment: No I am using python3.8, my apologizes I thought I was still operating in 3.7.  Is the matplotlib library not compatible with 3.8?